# Listen to the click event after use using the .load method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a little problem...

index.php

```
<div id="order"></div>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#order").load("modules/main.php?load=order");

    $("#sort li").on("click", function(){
        $("#items").load("modules/main.php?load=items&order="+order);
        console.log('try123');
    });
});
```

main.php?load=order

```
<ul class="sort" id="sort">
    <li data-order="najnovsie">Najnovšie</li>
    <li data-order="najpredavanejsie" class="select">Najpredávanejšie</li>
    <li data-order="najlacnejsie">Najlacnejšie</li>
</ul>
```

and do nothing when I click `#sort li`

Comment: where is the variable `order` being declared?

Answer (score 3):

Use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and attach the `click` event to the constant parent element, `#sort`.

```
$("#sort").on("click", "li", function(){
    $("#items").load("modules/main.php?load=items&order="+order);
    console.log('try123');
});
```